# Python Value Error working with data set

Tags: python, python-3.x

To whomever,

Having been given a data set of a few parameters (wavelength and 4 stokes parameters) I thought that I had set up everything correctly. [However it keeps showing me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zse1P.png). I know for a fact that the wavelength values are the only values in the string of data that have a decimal point in it. So I figured by inserting `float()` that I would be in the clear. However I guess I'm not. What exactly is holding back the program from interpreting the list of values especially when I tell it that there is a decimal number.

Whats going on here, code-wise, is that I set up the base with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as c
from scipy.interpolate import spline
```

and then haven been given data and it sitting in a file I set up some arrays

```
WL = np.array([])
SI = np.array([])
SQ = np.array([])
SU = np.array([])
SV = np.array([])
```

Where WL is measured wavelength (some value with a decimal) and S[I,Q,U,V] (integer value) are my stokes parameters. Then I tell python where to find said data in my computer and define who is who.

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Schmidt\\Desktop\\Python\\Homework_4\\CoolStuffLivesHere\\stokes_profiles_0.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split(' ')
        WL = np.append(WL, data[0])
        SI = np.append(SI, data[1])
        SQ = np.append(SQ, data[2])
        SU = np.append(SU, data[3])
        SV = np.append(SV, data[4])
```

Now this works and doesn't complain. However it does get upset when I ask for the program to

```
plt.plot(WL,SI)
plt.show()
```

saying that it "cannot convert string to float". So what I thought would work was by implementing the float around the one collection of decimal values (remember that wavelength is some value with a decimal) that is in the string of values.

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Schmidt\\Desktop\\Python\\Homework_4\\CoolStuffLivesHere\\stokes_profiles_0.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=line.split(' ')
        WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))
        SI = np.append(SI, data[1])
        SQ = np.append(SQ, data[2])
        SU = np.append(SU, data[3])
        SV = np.append(SV, data[4])
```

However this comes up with the same error. So I'm at a loss and am in need of assistance.

Comment: Please add the code and error in code blocks in this question so we don't have to go to other sites to see it.

Comment: A working example would be nice. Try printing `line` to find out the guilty data and then post an example that just does the split/float on that line. Use `print(repr(line))` so we can see everything in the line.

Comment: Your line isn't what you think it is. Suppose you have a line that's just some spaces that you split and convert: `float("    \n".split(" ")[1])` results in `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`. Since we still don't have any data to work with, I'm voting to close. You need to help us if we are to help you.

Comment: updated with code and error text, please review and if possible remove hold

Comment: for your **print(repr(line))** it returned with the following:

'       6300.8750   15199      73      21      14\n'

That is the very first line of data in the data set, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Worked on the file and now that same line (**print(repr(line))**) is rendering the following:

'\n'

Comment: ` ' 6300.8750 15199 73 21 14\n'` begins with a space so when you split it, it is `['', '6300.8750', '15199', '73', '21', '14\n']` and `data[0]` doesn't convert. You can fix that with `data = lines.strip().split(" ")`. Since your original complaint was with `data[1]` not `data[0]` you may have more random spaces. Splitting with regex may help `data = re.split(r' +', line.strip())`.

Comment: You could also add a check for an empty `data` list which would happen for blank lines.

Comment: So having updated the file and deleting random spaces, what should I be typing in then?

Comment: working on the second of 8 sets of data (these files have not been altered and therefore still have these _random spaces_) typing in the 'lines.strip().split(" ")' keeps returning 'lines not defined' is there perhaps something I am missing thats more preliminary. Again I typed the 'print(repr(line))' and it rendered the first line from that file.

Comment: Oops. meant `line.strip()` ... now that you are reopened I wrote up a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When processing data you have to decide how forgiving you are going to be with bad data. For an XML parser for instance, one missing end tag and the entire document is thrown away. In your case, you have extra spaces and empty lines in your data. The error you got is a perfectly reasonable failure if you want strict formatting of the document.

But you can check for conditions that you want to allow and relax the formattig rules a bit. In this example, I account for extra spaces in the string and allow empty lines. Lines that don't split to 5 fields get a warning.

```
# this should be at the top with your other imports
import re
# a regex that splits on any number of spaces
split_on_spaces = re.compile(" +").split

with open('C:\\Users\\Schmidt\\Desktop\\Python\\Homework_4\\CoolStuffLivesHere\\stokes_profiles_0.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=split_on_spaces(line.strip())
        if len(data) == 0:
            # skip blank line
            continue
        if len(data) != 5:
            # warn on bad lines
            sys.stderr.write("BAD LINE: {}".format(repr(line))
            continue
        WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))
        SI = np.append(SI, data[1])
        SQ = np.append(SQ, data[2])
        SU = np.append(SU, data[3])
        SV = np.append(SV, data[4])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Onto the next problem when plotting it I have this new problem of 'x and y must have same first dimension' and I don't know how to amend that. Also, mysteriously, although python returned an error there was still a graph produced?